# take path from fileUpload and Directory Browsing in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, directory

I'm trying to take a path from FileUpload tool in asp.net, but it seems impossible.

another thing,
I want to select a folder to save there my files, but i cannot find any tool that similar to 
Directory Browsing .

can someone help me please?

Comment: take a look :http://www.roxyfileman.com

Comment: do you need a tool to manage your file ?

Comment: i want that the user will choose file and i will get the path, and for the second question i want to choose a directory where i want to save files.

Comment: E A, i see the site but i don't know how to download it

Comment: http://www.roxyfileman.com/download.php?f=1.3.1-.net